# Как отснифать трафик Android приложения?

Tags: android, сеть, трафик, сниффер

1. В Burp Suite добавил прокси
2. На android эмуляторе установил ssl сертификат Burp с помощью android приложения "certificate no root manager"
3. На android эмуляторе в wifi добавил Burp прокси

Этот способ работает, но я стал снифать другое стороннее приложение и там выходит "ошибка соединения".
Возможно из-за того, что приложение понимает подмену сертификата или есть какая-либо защита.

Как мне решить эту проблему?
Какие способы отснифать андроид трафик вы знаете?

Comment: есть еще Фидлер (сам активно юзаю) и Чарльз (только видел). но там будет точно такая же проблема. я, если пропускаю трафик через Фидлер, не могу даже гугл запрос сделать.

Comment: Если используется certificate pinning, то никак.